# How does a reputation loss of 3 arise ?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

This is just out of curiosity. I just noted that my reputation on Stackoverflow was reduced by 3. There was no indication in the reputation summary, so I guess some user left and some of my points were somehow related to his questions/answers. Actually I don't really bother, but what makes me curious is how it is possible to lose an amount of 3 points this way ? 2, 5 or 10 I could understand. I'd assume one would also need to be able to get a similar increase somehow, something which I cannot recall in my case.

Comment: A question with one upvote and one downvote?

Comment: Check the 'show removed posts' checkbox at the bottom of your reputation page to see if any posts were removed. If you had *gained* 3 points for a post (question upvote +5 plus a downvote, -2 perhaps?) you'd have lost that again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that was it. One of my questions got removed. Could have thought of that myself ;-)